# Taking feats while multiclassing

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Let's suppose that we have a multiclassing barbarian/PRC. The character has 6 levels of Barbarian and does not intend to take any more, focusing on leveling as a rogue. However, the player would like to have an additional Rage Power. For this purpose, the player would like to take Extra Rage Power feat to select some Rage Power that he qualifies for (e.g. Lesser Beast Totem). However, the PRC he has chosen (Mammoth Rider) has no progression of rage feature.

Extra Rage Power feat says:

> ### Extra Rage Power
>
> You have unlocked a new ability to use while raging.
>   **Prerequisite: Rage power class feature**.
>   Benefit: You gain one additional rage power. You must meet all of the
>   prerequisites for this rage power.
>   Special: You can gain Extra Rage Power multiple times.

after APG, emphasis mine

Can he select Extra Rage Power while taking a level in Mammoth Rider by the virtue of him being able to rage at all, or can feats that have "class feature" prereq be taken only while leveling in a class with said feature?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Feat prerequisite with do not care about what class you took at the level you gained them, only that you have the feature. Once your character has the Rage power feature from barbarian he is always considered to have it and therefore fulfills the prerequisite; He doesn't loose it by taking a level in another class.

MrLemon said it very well in the comments below:
Think of it this way: Feat prerequisites concern things written on the character sheet. If it says Rage Power, you qualify for Extra Rage Power. If it says Strength 13 (or more) and Power Attack, you qualify for Cleave.

Comment: Think of it this way: Feat prerequisites concern things written on the character sheet. If it says *Rage Power*, you qualify for *Extra Rage Power*. If it says Strength 13 (or more) and *Power Attack*, you qualify for *Cleave*.

Comment: I like that @MrLemon, I shall add it to the answer, so that it doesn't get lost if the comments get long.

Comment: One of the specific design decisions when they were making 3e was that feats would never require classes. They might be built on things that only a specific class would have, but never do they require a class as a prerequisite.

Comment: @Zach That's not really true. There are some feats that have "Fighter level X" as a pre-req. Check this, for example: http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Greater_Weapon_Focus

Comment: It is a 3.x guideline, but they break it a few times for Weapon Spec, related feats, and similar corner cases.